# How to run a pattern without using delay()

Tags: arduino, delay

I want to run an LED pattern again and again using the `for()`, and without interrupting the other code that is running. But have encountered the problem of using `delay()` too much.

So, the BlinkWithoutDelay example repeats only one thing: turn the LED on, and off every second. If I were to do it with a pattern (and not just turning the LED on and off), how would I do it?

The problem is with `millis()`

What other options are there of running a pattern without using delay?

Comment: Seems like you have a logic problem and not really a coding problem.  You should be able to display any pattern you want using the correct if statements to toggle stuff just like in the BlinkWithoutDelay example.

Comment: can you add the relevant code to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Agree your code would be nice to see, to underdatnd what you're trying to do.  Assuming that the changes come LESS often than a loop without delay()'s in it, you can either use [interrupts](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AttachInterrupt) (actually very easy to set up on the arduino) or a library called [Metro](http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/Metro) that lets you trigger timed events without using delay() or interrupts.

Comment: This tutorial explains timer ints pretty well. http://www.electronicsblog.net/examples-of-using-arduinoatmega-16-bit-hardware-timer-for-digital-clock/

Answer (score 0):

You've two options if you want to display a sequence, and have something else going on in the background.

First, you could sprinkle your sequence within the main `loop()`. It looks like a good few of the "LED chasers" and "KnightRider" effects on the internet are coded like this.

```
void loop () {
    // do something
    digitalWrite();
    // do something
    digitalWrite();
}
```

Or, you can use timer interrupts. This is a bit trickier to set up, but again, a quick internet search should bring up loads of examples. In this case, run the timer on the Arduino and set up the interrupts to trigger every xns. This will let the main loop do what it's doing, and every xns there will be a quick interruption to update your sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a time sensitive pattern, you might want to try using timer interrupts.

The tutorial [here](http://letsmakerobots.com/node/28278) has a pretty good explanation and several examples of how to use the Arduino timer interrupts.

If you want to run the code while the led pattern is going on, I don't think it is possible on the arduino. That requires parallel processing of the code.